# Cannot able to remove the subfolder directory from url in Codeigniter using routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following directory structure in Controller :

```
Controllers
  |__ posts
      |__ post.php

views
  |__ welcome_message.php
  |__ home.php
```

> welcome_message.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="<?php echo site_url("posts/post/posts_controller"); ?>">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

> home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter Link Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>This is the link page</h1>

<div id="body">
    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> welcome.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

> post.php

```
<?php

Class Post extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function posts_controller()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

}
?>
```

when i click on link in welcome_message.php i get following url `http://localhost/url_routing/posts/post/posts_controller` but i want to remove posts (i.e. folder name) from url so i tried `$route['posts'] = "post/posts_controller";` in routes.php folder but the result is same. So please help me to solve my issue, and if possible give me a small explanation of that, i have seen others answers from stackoverflow but can't understand completely.

Comment: whats your default base url?

Comment: @cos nik: this is my base url: http://localhost/url_routing/

Comment: if i am correct you want to see the home view in this url: localhost/url/routing/post/posts_controller?

Comment: i mean localhost/url_routing/post/posts_controller?

Comment: why routing in the url. This should be url http://localhost/url_routing/posts/post/posts_controller (posts is the folder name in the controller)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102834/discussion-between-user3653474-and-cos-nik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route['post/posts_controller'] = 'posts/post/posts_controller';
```